# Imessage / apple ID

Tags: messages

My wife and my children have iphones under her apple ID , I have an android Galaxy Note 3 ... today my wife sent a couple inappropriate texts to me and I responded ... later today one of my children told my wife that they were getting her texts .. would they have gotten mine from an Android or just the texts of other imessage users ?

Comment: short answer- yes

Answer (score 2):

Sharing the appleId is the issue.

The only way to solve the problem is to at the very least put the phones on different appleId's for iMessage.

If you open the Settings app, you will discover that iCloud, iTunes and App Store, Messages(iMessage), Facetime, Game Center, and perhaps Mail, Contact and Calenders all can be configured to use separate appleId's.   The simplist thing to do is use the same appleId for all, but there can be reasons for mixing.

AppleId's aren't meant to be shared between people, it's really better if you give each user there own, even the kids. Family sharing can be used to unify purchases across all.   Family Sharing and Parental controls are the topics you should learn about next.